# Shiny R + Leaflet SearchInput Default to Show All Points

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm designing a web page that includes a leaflet map, location data as a .csv and ShinyApp in R. I have managed to get the search bar to work via searchInput in my side bar, however, I am having trouble getting it to function correctly.

What happens now? Map defaults to showing no points. This was not an issue before the search bar worked and while the rest of the inputs did. When I search a name, the point shows up. When I clear the search, the map is blank again.

What I want to happen? I want all the points to show on the map by default. When I search a name, only that point should show up. After I clear the search, all the points should show back up again. So it is effectively a filter like the other inputs but I do not want a drop down menu of thousands of individual names, hence a search input. My Global, UI and Server code is below. I have not tried much because I am having a hard time conceptualizing this as I am very new. I applied what I could from the other inputs but am at a loss since the search input seems to function differently.

Thanks,

Rob

**Global:**

```
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(leafem)
deaths <- read.csv ("Shinydata.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**UI:**

```
        library(shiny)
        
        ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
          tags$head(tags$style(
            HTML('
                 #sidebar {
                    background-color: #c0c0c0;w
                 }
               
        
                body, label, input, button, select { 
                  font-family: "Garamond";
                }')
          )),
            
            
            column(offset=6,width=5, titlePanel(("Say Their Names Map" )
            )),
            setBackgroundColor("#778899"),
          
            sidebarPanel(id="sidebar", 
              
              # Input: Select Year ----
              sliderInput(inputId = "yearrange", "Select a Year Range", min=2014, max=2020, value=c(2014, 2020), sep = ""),
              
              # Input: Select Work ----
              selectInput(inputId = "year", "Select a Year", choices=c("All", sort(unique(as.character(deaths$Year))))),
              
              selectInput(inputId = "gender", "Select a Gender", choices=c("All", sort(unique(as.character(deaths$Gender))))),
              
              selectInput(inputId = "state", "Select a Sate", choices=c("All", sort(unique(as.character(deaths$State),)))),
              
              searchInput(
                inputId = "search", label = "Search by Name",
                btnSearch = icon("search"),
                btnReset = icon("remove"),
                
               
                
              ),
              
              
              
              width = 2),
            mainPanel(leafletOutput("map", height=675, width = 1225),
          )
        ))
```

**Server:**

```
    shinyServer(function (input, output) {
    
      
      
      filtered_map <- reactive({
        rows <- (deaths$Year<=input$yearrange[2] & deaths$Year>=input$yearrange[1]) &
          (input$year == "All" | deaths$Year==input$year) &
          (input$gender == "All" | deaths$Gender==input$gender) &
          (input$state == "All" | deaths$State==input$state) &
          (input$search_search == "" | deaths$Victimsname==input$search)&
          (input$search_reset == ""| deaths$Victimsname==input$search)
        
        deaths[rows,,drop = FALSE] 
      })
      
    
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(deaths) %>%
        setView(lng = -97.312891, lat = 38.49024, zoom = 4,) %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter", options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE, minZoom=4,maxZoom=10)) %>%
       
        
        
        addCircleMarkers(lng=filtered_map()[["Longitude"]], lat=filtered_map()[["Latitude"]],radius=3,color = ("DarkRed"), 
                   popup=paste("<b>", filtered_map()[["Victimsname"]], "</b><br/>",
                               "Age:", filtered_map()[["Age"]], "<br>",
                               "City:", filtered_map()[["City"]], "<br>"),
                     # clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
        )
    })
    })
```